# How do I get a comma-delimited list of strings from an XML column in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

Suppose there is a table (SQL Server 2019) with two columns. Both are nvarchar but the `ResultDoc` column happens to store xml. Example data:

| Name | ResultDoc |
| --- | --- |
| Sam | `<doc><results><result>a</result><result>b</result><result>x</result></results></doc>` |
| Jan | `<doc><results><result>c</result><result type="pending">z</result><result>m</result><result>k</result></results></doc>` |

I want to be able to query this table, filtering on the xml, and get a result like this:

| Name | Results |
| --- | --- |
| Sam | a, b, x |
| Jan | c, m, k |

I've seen examples that do this for a single document, but I haven't been able to work a solution like that into a query that does this for several rows.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated** ... moved the aggregate into the OUTER APPLY

Since you are on 2019, you can use `string_agg()`

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b34e81991e0d427e66f038768a884e06)**

```
Select A.Name
      ,C.Results
 From  YourTable A
 Outer Apply ( values (try_convert(xml,[ResultDoc]) ) )B(xmlData)
 Outer Apply (
                Select Results = string_Agg(xn.value('./text()[1]', 'nvarchar(150)'),',')
                 From xmlData.nodes('doc/results/result') C(xn)
                 Where coalesce(xn.value('@type[1]', 'nvarchar(150)'),'') not in ('pending')
              ) C
```

**Results**

```
Name    Results
Jan     c,m,k
Sam     a,b,x
```